# How to find out if the app is being run in Bokeh or not?

Tags: python, bokeh

In my Bokeh .py app, run by Bokeh server, I'm importing a module. In this module, a part of code depends on whether it is used in the Bokeh app or not (it can be used in "normal" Python script, too). How do I know whether the code is currently being used by Bokeh server or not?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no code available to assist you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a bokeh process is running with [psutil](https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-by-name-and-find-its-process-id-pid/). I have also made an [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py) where show is used when a bokeh process is running (server) or show when no bokeh prcoess is running ("normal").

```
import psutil
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;

# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="my sine wave",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[0, 4*np.pi], y_range=[-2.5, 2.5])

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)


# Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1, step=0.1)


# Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

for w in [offset, amplitude, phase, freq]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = column(text, offset, amplitude, phase, freq)

if checkIfProcessRunning('bokeh'):
    print('A bokeh process is running')
    curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
    curdoc().title = "Sliders"
else:
    print('No bokeh process is running')
    show(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
```